# Python search for string in line

Tags: python, string, replace, substitution

I have the following code, which I think should work, but doesn't appear to:

```
old_name = 'Some User'
new_name = 'New User'

with open(complete_filename, 'r') as provisioning_file:
   lines = provisioning_file.read()
   # if the old_name is in this file
   if old_name in lines:
     file_found = 1
     with open(complete_filename + '.new', 'w') as new_provisioning_file:
       for line in lines:
         line = line.replace(old_name, new_name)
         new_provisioning_file.write(line)
         # provisioning_file.write(re.sub(old_name, new_name, line))
```

The file `complete_filename` will be a variety of config files, I have been testing with a selection of XML files, an example snippet of one of these is below:

```
  <reg reg.1.address="1234" reg.1.label="Some User" >
        <reg.1.auth reg.1.auth.password="XXXXXXXXXX" reg.1.auth.userId="1234" />
        <reg.1.outboundProxy reg.1.outboundProxy.address="sip.example.com" />
        <reg.1.server reg.1.server.1.address="sip.example.com" reg.1.server.1.expires="300" reg.1.server.2.expires="300" />
        <reg.1.serverFeatureControl reg.1.serverFeatureControl.dnd="0" />
     </reg>
```

The code finds the `old_name` string and goes into the `if` statement, then opens `complete_filename.new` for writing, but it apparently never finds the old name in the lines and just outputs the file as-is (i.e. it does not substitute `new_name` for `old_name`).

As can be seen from the code I have also experimented with re.sub with similar results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lines = provisioning_file.read()
```

This doesn't look right to me. `read()` doesn't return a list of lines, it returns a single string. So later on when you do `for line in lines:`, you're not iterating line-by-line, you're iterating one character at a time.

Try `split`ting the object before iterating over it. I also suggest changing its name so it better describes its contents.

```
with open(complete_filename, 'r') as provisioning_file:
   text= provisioning_file.read()
   # if the old_name is in this file
   if old_name in text:
     file_found = 1
     with open(complete_filename + '.new', 'w') as new_provisioning_file:
       for line in text.split("\n"):
         line = line.replace(old_name, new_name)
         new_provisioning_file.write(line + "\n")
```

---

Edit: alternate approach:

```
old_name = 'Some User'
new_name = 'New User'

with open(complete_filename, 'r') as provisioning_file:
   lines = provisioning_file.readlines()
   # if the old_name is in this file
   if any(old_name in line for line in lines):
     file_found = 1
     with open(complete_filename + '.new', 'w') as new_provisioning_file:
       for line in lines:
         line = line.replace(old_name, new_name)
         new_provisioning_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I guess then an alternative would be `lines = provisioning_file.readlines()`? Would this be another way to solve? and then iterate as I am already.

Comment: Yes, and in fact that may be preferable since then you don't have to manually write newline characters in the `write` call. But you would have to modify your conditional to `if any(old_name in line for line in lines)`, since `in` doesn't do partial matching on the contents of a list. (ex. `"a" in ["ab", "cd"]` evaluates to False)

Comment: I tried this but got a syntax error on the conditional, any chance you could show me this in a snippet in context?

Comment: Sure, edited. Maybe it's because I forgot the colon?